# RegularExpressionValidator is not working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

My RegularExpressValidator1 does not fire.  Not sure what is missing below.  Any suggestion?

```
<td class="txtbox1"><asp:TextBox ID="txtCard" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                               ControlToValidate="txtCard" 
                               Forecolor="Red"
                               ValidationExpression="(0*[1-9]\d*)" runat="server" 
                               ErrorMessage = "Enter numeric number only.">
                          </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                     </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at Microsoft's page [How To: Use Regular Expressions to constrain input in ASP.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx).

> Enclosing the expression in the caret (^) and dollar sign ($)markers ensures that the expression consists of the desired content and nothing else. A ^ matches the position at the beginning of the input string and a $ matches the position at the end of the input string. If you omit these markers, an attacker could affix malicious input to the beginning or end of valid content and bypass your filter.

If you scroll down to the section titled **Common Regular Expressions**, it includes a RegEx for positive integers:

```
^\d+$
```

---

Their pattern restricts the input to *only* numbers, whereas yours seems like it's only checking to see if a number is included in any fashion.

As an example, consider this input:

```
1234 and text!
```

**Using `^\d+$`** [(Source)](http://regexr.com/3fve4)

```
0 matches
```

**Using `(0*[1-9]\d*)`** [(Source)](http://regexr.com/3fve7)

```
1 match: 1234
```

---

As an unrelated note, I'd suggest modifying your placeholder text from *"Enter a numeric number only."* to something like *"Enter a number"* or *"Enter a numeric value"*, as "numeric number" is a bit redundant!

Comment: Hi Santi, thank you for your comments.  I tried ^\d+$, ^[0-9]$, and ^\d+$ options.  None of this fire up the validation.  It does not matter whether I enter numbers or characters, it will accept anything.  I think my issue is related to not firing the validation.